# String parsing to manipulate each token (without STL)

Tags: c++, string, parsing

This is a Homework question but I've already completed it, this is more just for my understanding. Just to add, I COULD NOT USE STL :(

Basically we were to implement a 'Student' class that has 5 parameters (first/last names, ID, grade, and major). Each Student object must then be stored in an array (lets call it classroom).

My issue comes when the user is adding a new student. At first my code just took each parameter like so:

```
cin >> first >> last >> id >> grade >> major;
```

And then pass those on to another function that stores it in the array. This works fine if the user enters everything as they should, an example input:

```
students> add John Smith 123 Freshman Computerscience
```

But when entered incorrectly, specifically with the ID input (its an int) like so:

```
students> add John Smith 123abc Freshman Computerscience
```

It would take 'abc' as the grade and 'Freshman' as the major, spitting out an error for the rest.

So I decided to take the whole input as a single string and parse it out, here's that code:

```
    class Student {
    private:
        string first_name;
        string last_name;
        int ID;
        string classification;
        string major;
    public:
        Student();

        /* Main class functions */
        void add(string, string, int, string, string);
        void print(string);
        bool remove(int);

        /* Helper class functions */
        bool empty();
        bool ifexist(int);
    };

  int main() 
     {
        bool done = false;
        string command, first, last, grade, major;
        int id;
        string query, input;
        string inputArray[6];
        string token = " ";
        while(!done) {
            cout << prompt;
            cin >> command;

            if(command == "add")
            {
                /* Get new student info */
                cin >> first >> last >> id >> grade >> major;;

                // this commented code is my attempt to fix error
                // count = 0;
                // while(getline(cin, input)) {
                //  stringstream s(input);
                //  while(s >> token) {
                //      inputArray[count] = token;
                //      count++;
                //  }
                //  if(count == 5) break;
                // }

                // first = inputArray[0];
                // last  = inputArray[1];
                // if(atoi(inputArray[2].c_str()))
                //  id= atoi(inputArray[2].c_str());
                // else cout << ERROR_INPUT << endl; 
                // grade = inputArray[3];
                // major = inputArray[4];

                // for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                //  cout << inputArray[i] << endl;
                // }
                //cout << first << endl << last << endl << id << endl << grade << endl << major << endl;

                int i = getInsertPoint();
                bool e = ifexist(id);

                /* Check if student already exists */
                if(e) cout << "Error! Already exists, try again" << endl;
                else  classroom[i].add(first, last, id, grade, major); 
            }
            else if(command == "print") 
            {
                /* Get query type to be printed (ex: firstname) */
                cin >> query;
                print(query);
            }
            else if(command == "remove")
            {
                cin >> id;
                remove(id);
            }
            else if(command == "quit") done = true;
            else cout << ERROR_INPUT << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I can print out the array and everything comes out fine, but when I pass each into the function that stores it in an object nothing appears. It does work however, when I use the first code I mentioned.

So my question is this: Is there a better way to parse/check an input string (w/o STL) that allows me to send each token individually to another function?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you can and cannot use? STL is a somewhat outdated term that means different things to different people.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "without STL", you are already using `string`, `stringstream`, *etc.* from the the standard library.

Comment: Also, please reduce your program to the smallest possible complete program that demonstrates the error. You mention a lot of code that isn't in your post. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more info.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I cannot use boost or algorithm or of that nature. I will edit for more complete understanding.

Comment: Where is your `Student` class? And what is the declaration for `classroom`?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop structure is somewhat broken. Depending on your intent that may be a problem:

```
while(getline(cin, input)) {
    stringstream s(input);
    while(s >> token) {
      inputArray[count] = token;
      count++;
```

Here you will happily continue, even you accumulate more than the 6 words your array can handle. If this happens, the behavior of the program becomes undefined.

```
    }
    if(count == 5) break; //got everything I need
```

So if you accumulated exactly 5 words (of the 6 your array can accommodate) you will process those five words. If you have less than 5 words, you will continue to accumulate additional words from the next line. You will stop only, if "parsing" one or more (up to 5) non-empty lines yields exactly 5 words. If you ever cross the 5 word limit (for example if the first line has 4 words and second at least 2) you will continue until input ends or the program crashes, because you are writing all over memory.

```
  }
```

Your use of `atoi()` will accept invalid input (like "123abc"). On the other hand your code will misbehave when the space is missing by accident ("123Freshman").

So my answer to your question is: yes, there are better ways to parse and check input. But unless you can clearly state the rules for your input, we can't help you fix your code. Also it isn't clear, what you mean, when you ask for ways "to send each token individually to another function".

Taken verbatim, the answer would be:

```
string token;
while (getline(cin, token)) { 
   another_function(token);
}
```

We can't tell you why things don't work "when [you] pass each into the function that stores it in an object", if you don't show us a complete example (code and input): what you expect to happen, what you see instead. We also can't tell you why results differ from "the first code [you] mentioned.", if you don't show us that code either.